# Route breaks Single Entry

Tags: entries, routes, singles

I'm following the [documentation](http://sprout.barrelstrengthdesign.com/craft-plugins/forms/docs/examples/adding-a-thank-you-page) to create a thank-you page when the user submits the form.

I have a single created for `/contact-us/` and I want the user to be redirected to `/contact-us/thank-you/` when they submit the form.

I have created the route so `contact-us/thank-you` shows the `contact-us` template, but when I go to that URL I get a template error saying `Variable "entry" does not exist`.

So it looks like it's showing the template correctly, but not loading the data from the single.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Craft automatically includes the [`entry` variable](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel) if the [slug matches the url](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/routing):

> If the URI matches an entry’s or category’s URI, the
>   section’s/category group’s template will get loaded, and the matched
>   element will be made available to the template via a pre-populated
>   entry or category variable.

In your case `contact-us` gets matched automatically, but `contact-us/thank-you` does not. This means you have to set `entry` yourself.

Just add this to the top of your template:

```twig
{% if entry is not defined %}
    {% set entry = craft.entries.section('contact-us').first() %}
    {# Fetch single which has 'contact-us' as a handle #}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: I had tried that before, I get the following error: `Impossible to access an attribute ("backgroundImage") on a NULL variable ("")`, with this being the code thats erroring: `{% set image       = entry.backgroundImage.first() %}`

Comment: If this only happens on the `thank-you` page, it means the `entry` variable is empty. My example works for a Single with the handle `contact-us`. Is your contact page a Single or a Channel/Structure entry?

Comment: You were right, I was getting the slug `contact-us` and the handle `contactUs` mixed up. Now I've got the correct handle in it works.